# Average of continuous not null values in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to add average of continuous not null values in a dataframe
Below picture shows input, required output and description of output.

[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with groups created by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with test missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and assign only for rows with non missing values with invert mask by `~`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Input':[5,6,7,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,13,32,12]})

m = df['Input'].isna()

df.loc[~m, 'output'] = df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum())['Input'].transform('mean')
print (df)
   Input  output
0    5.0     6.0
1    6.0     6.0
2    7.0     6.0
3    NaN     NaN
4    NaN     NaN
5    NaN     NaN
6   13.0    19.0
7   32.0    19.0
8   12.0    19.0
```